# xattr: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: terminal, python, utilities, darwin

When I execute the `xattr` command, it returns the error:

```
/usr/local/bin/xattr: /usr/local/opt/python@3.11/bin/python3.11: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

`file /usr/bin/xattr` returns:

```
/usr/bin/xattr: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures: [x86_64:Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64] [arm64e:Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64e]
/usr/bin/xattr (for architecture x86_64):   Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
/usr/bin/xattr (for architecture arm64e):   Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64e
```

`which python3` returns `/usr/bin/python3` and my `env` doesn't have any python entries.

This is my `.zshrc` file:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"

# Created by `pipx` on 2023-11-25 17:42:38
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/rhpt/.local/bin"
```

I do not have python 3.11 but I do have python 3.12 installed. Running Sonoma 14.2 on an Intel iMac.

I do not understand why `xattr` is trying to execute a python script. How can I get Terminal to use the executable instead of trying to execute python?

Comment: You installed a third-party xattr with Homebrew or something like that, and it's faulty or missing a dependency. If you want to use the system xattr, invoke it with the full path or create a shell alias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error comes from `/usr/local/bin/xattr`, but you examine `/usr/bin/xattr`. So either remove the one in local, or replace `/usr/local/opt/python@3.11/bin/python3.11` in the first line of the script with a path to an actually installed python version.